# deploy notebooks to azure devops using rest api

Tags: python, rest, azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-devops-rest-api

Hi i want to deploy python notebooks to azure databricks using rest api is there a way to achieve that if you could provide me with any documentations or links to refer it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

One of the first steps in designing a CI/CD pipeline is deciding on a code commit and branching strategy to manage the development and integration of new and updated code without adversely affecting the code currently in production. Part of this decision involves choosing a version control system to contain your code and facilitate the promotion of that code. Azure Databricks supports integrations with GitHub and Bitbucket, which allow you to commit notebooks to a git repository.

If your version control system is not among those supported through direct notebook integration, or if you want more flexibility and control than the self-service git integration, you can use the Databricks CLI to export notebooks and commit them from your local machine.

You can refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops#deploy-the-notebooks-to-the-workspace) for code samples and steps.